# How to split the data frame into different groups based on the specified column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have a big data containing 100 colunms with respective four different column names, I want to separate them into four different data frames based on their names.

I have been struggling with this problem for hours. It might be something trivial, but I was unable to figure out (I'm new for coding). I am looking forward to any correction and suggestion.
Thanks a lot!

I was trying to create a list of data frames named "split_dfs", and assigned elements to each separated groups by using for loop. I expected that "split_dfs" should contains separate data frames for each group of columns. However, the print(split_dfs) shows NULL. It seems that the elements weren't added to the list() successfully.

my data:(example)

```
<df>
A      B     C     B     D     A     C    C     B   
0.6   0.1   0.3   0.4   0.2   0.1   0.3  0.9   0.9
0.9   0.81  0.5   0.73  0.3   0.8   0.5  0.8   0.1
0.18  0.7   0.79  0.3   0.5   0.4   0.7  0.4   0.4
```

Expected result(get four separated dataframes with all row's values):

```
<group A>        
A                
0.6      
0.9   
0.18 
0.1
0.8
0.4 

<group B>
B
0.1
0.81
0.7
0.9
0.1
0.4 

<group C>
C
0.3
0.5
0.79
0.3
0.5
0.7
0.9
0.8
0.4

<group D>
D
0.2
0.3
0.5
```

Code that I used:

```
col_groups = list(
  c("A"),
  c("B"),
  c("C"),
  c("D")
)

split_dfs = list()
for(i in names(col_groups)){
  selected_cols = col_groups[[i]]
  split_dfs[[i]] = new_df[, selected_cols, drop = FALSE]
}
```

Comment: Is group B missing some values in your expected result? Or do you only want distinct values?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that

```
split_by_col_name <- function(data, cols=unique(names(data))) {
    Map(function(x) unname(unlist(data[which(names(data)==x)])), cols)
}
split_by_col_name(df)
# $A
# [1] 0.60 0.90 0.18 0.10 0.80 0.40
# $B
# [1] 0.10 0.81 0.70 0.40 0.73 0.30 0.90 0.10 0.40
# $C
# [1] 0.30 0.50 0.79 0.30 0.50 0.70 0.90 0.80 0.40
# $D
# [1] 0.2 0.3 0.5
```

We map over the unique names and subset them and combine them together.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `pivot_longer` to reshape the data.

Note, not using `group_split` from tidyverse because it drops group names. Also, strictly speaking the initial data frame is invalid because it has duplicated names.

```
library(tidyr)

split(df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()), colnames(df))
$A
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      0.6 
2 A      0.1 
3 A      0.9 
4 A      0.8 
5 A      0.18
6 A      0.4 

$B
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 B      0.1 
2 B      0.4 
3 B      0.9 
4 B      0.81
5 B      0.73
6 B      0.1 
7 B      0.7 
8 B      0.3 
9 B      0.4 

$C
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 C      0.3 
2 C      0.3 
3 C      0.9 
4 C      0.5 
5 C      0.5 
6 C      0.8 
7 C      0.79
8 C      0.7 
9 C      0.4 

$D
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 D       0.2
2 D       0.3
3 D       0.5
```